# Best practice for caching expensive lists of non-rendered data in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

This is a general question, but to get the point across, let's discuss a specific example.  Suppose you have an application that frequently uses forms that include a list of all the countries in the world. The countries are stored in the `countries` table in your DB, but this table is updated very very rarely, and only through your seeds.rb file.

In order to be able to shave off a little time in each request, I typically manage this sort of thing as follows:

```
module ApplicationHelper

    def self.get_countries
        countries = Country.order("name asc").all.collect{|country| [country.name, country.name]}
        countries.unshift(["",""])
        countries
    end

    # In production mode (cache_classes = true) this is executed only once, and 
    # will remain cached until you restart your application server
    @@COUNTRIES =  ApplicationHelper.get_countries

    # This would be called from various views
    def countries_for_select(country)
        selected = country.name unless country.nil?
        options_for_select(@@COUNTRIES, selected)
    end
end
```

Is this a reasonable approach?

Please don't suggest *not* storing the list of countries in the database.  I'm aware there are other ways to manage lists of countries.  I'm not really concerned with countries - it's just the easiest to understand example I could think of to illustrate this general question.

Comment: First, if you are only running that query against the countries table, it is likely that your DB is caching the result set since each request, that query will come in one time (presumably) if you remove your caching code.  So the amount of time required will probably only be large when your DB is populating its query cache.
Second, not sure what you're asking for - if you really want to cache the results, this seems like a fine solution (assuming `@@COUNTRIES` actually remains cached during the server's uptime).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "non-rendered data". With your method, the form view still needs to loop through all of the countries and render an option for the select for each one.

```
<select id="user_country" name="user[country]">
  <option value="US">United States</option>
  <option value="CA">Canada</option>
  <option value="ET">Etcetera</option>
```

If, however, you wrapped the select in a fragment cache, then the first time the form was rendered after the last deploy, the select options would be rendered and then cached into a separate file in /tmp/cache. Then on every subsequent time the form is loaded, that cached file would be used by rails as if it were a partial and inserted into the form.

```
<% form_for @user do |form| %>
  <% cache('user_countries_selector') do %>
    <% form.select :country, Country.order("name asc").all.collect{|country [country.name, country.name]}
  <% end %>
  <% etc, etc, etc %>
<% end %>
```

although, in practice, I would probably move the `Country.order...` code out to a helper method. Caching the list of countries to @@COUNTRIES is completely unnecessary with this method.

If you need to render a country select in other forms, you should pass a different key to `cache()` since the id and name of the rendered select tag will be form specific.

Comment: Yeah, I considered caching the rendered fragment, but then if the user is editing an object, how would you set the selected country to whichever country they had previous selected? (E.g. suppose it was in an address form, and the previously saved country was Canada.  If you fragment cache the actual HTML, how do you select "Canada" when the user edits the address?)

Comment: By "non-rendered" I meant "caching outside the view layer" due to the difficulty mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Gotcha. And that's a good point on caching the previously selected option, but it wouldn't just cache the previously selected option by that person, it would cache the option selected by whomever loaded that form first since the last deploy, making that pretty much a non-solution.